# VF: Custom controller with custom text

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom controller and I am trying to populate a custom picklist with text other than the object name field. I have two objects Course and Course Detail. They have a Master-Detail Relationship.

I have a function called CourseDetailMultiselect. It populates my custom picklist. It runs a SOQL statement. I am trying to pull the course name and then concatenate it into a string. Then I use that string as the output to the picklist.

```
public CourseDetailMultiselect() {
    selectedCourseDt = new List<SelectOption>();

    List<Course_Detail__c> courses = [SELECT Course_Detail__c.Course__c.Name, StartDate, Id FROM Course_Detail__c];    
    allCourseDt = new List<SelectOption>();
    for ( Course_Detail__c c : courses ) {
        string temp = c.Course_Detail__c.Course__c.Name + "-" + c.StartDate;
        allCourseDt.add(new SelectOption(c.Id, temp));
    }
}
```

When I try to save the class I get the following error:

```
Didn't understand relationship 'Course__c' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Answer (score 0):

Referenced the wrong object and added '__r' instead of '__c'.

```
public CourseDetailMultiselect() {
    selectedCourseDt = new List<SelectOption>();

    List<Course_Detail__c> courses = [SELECT Course_Detail__c.Course__c.Name, StartDate, Id FROM Course_Detail__c];    
    allCourseDt = new List<SelectOption>();
    for ( Course_Detail__c c : courses ) {
        string temp = c.Course_Detail__c.FKCourse__r.Name + "-" + c.StartDate;
        allCourseDt.add(new SelectOption(c.Id, temp));
    }
}
```